# Update Checked table Rows

Tags: laravel

I need to update checked table rows at once

I tried the code below to update a certain column but it only works when I want to delete checked rows

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="{{ $user->id }}"/></td>
```

```
public function update(Request $request) 

    {
        $checked = $request->input('selected',[]);
        User::whereIn('id', $checked)->update(['status' => 1]);
        return redirect('/home/users');
    }
```

I want to be able to update checked rows at once.

Comment: What do you mean by working when you want to delete checked rows and not working on update? Which are the routes you defined?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong syntax in your `update` function, you should either use:

```
User::whereIn('id', $checked)->update('status', 1);
```

or

```
User::whereIn('id', $checked)->update(['status' => 1]);
```

Comment: sorry it was a typo, but still the same question

Comment: When you post the form, have you tried dumping the results of your checked array using `dd($checked);` to make sure you get the ids of the selected users?

Comment: I have a form which I'm using to delete selected rows how can I add another form for updating the rows. Because I was using an anchor tag `<a  href="{{ route('status.update')}}">Update Status</a>`

Comment: if you want to reuse the same form, you should use JavaScript in order to perform both actions. So using JavaScript you should change the method type and endpoint based on the button clicked.

Answer (score 0):

if you go through `echo"<pre>";print_r($checked);die;` you will see `$checked` is an array. So, execute a `foreach` loop and you will get each `id` as string. Then update it. Also update it as an array in `->update()` .

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="{{ $user->id }}"/>{{$user->name}}</td>

public function update(Request $request) 
{
    $input = $request->all();
    foreach ($input['selected'] as $select) {
        User::update(array('user_id' => $select->id), [
            'status' => '1',
        ]);

    }
    return redirect('/home/users');
}
```

Comment: i think update or create is wrong here since the user will be selection from a users select box (so it already exists) + why will u create a user with with no data except the ID & status?

Comment: You can used only update or create Please check edited post.